# Why is this MySQL query slow when conditions are combined, but fast when they are separated?

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing, query-optimization

So suppose I have this query:

```
select * from tablea where budget > 100 and users > 1000
```

Separate queries:

```
select * from tablea where budget > 100
```

and

```
select * from tablea where users > 1000
```

Complete in 0.01~ seconds

However, when the conditions are combined the query takes 1-2 seconds to complete.

I have a index on both columns (budget, user).

Does any smart person on SOF know why this is happening, and how to **optimize** it in this case?

Extra notes:

- When the first query is run, there is 100000 rows, 100000 rows for
  the second query, and 3 rows when the queries are combined
- The table has over 1mil rows
- EXPLAIN shows that the compound index (budget, user) is used: EXPLAIN EXTENDED shows that there are 1477594 rows, and about 50% are filtered

Comment: It´s possible that your buffer cache is too low so the joining iterations are generating IO. This is quite unlikely though. How about you show the extended plan?

Comment: added it onto the question

Comment: how many columns are there in your **tablea**?

Comment: only the 2 in the query

Comment: I meant the actual table. Some information pieces are interesting, like buffer, temp, use index, use where etc.

Comment: We cannot address your question without `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: No way.  MySQL cannot return 100K rows in 10ms.  Perhaps you (or your tool) included a `LIMIT`??  If you answer 'yes', then the answer is simple.

Answer (score 0):

`EXPLAIN` doesn't really know, so it says exactly 50%.  Don't trust that.

You used a `LIMIT`, and early in the table were that many rows that met the single criteria.

But it had to scan the entire table to find the 3 rows for the combined filter.

No index is useful for two ranges (`budget > 100 and users > 1000`), but either of these will help:

```
INDEX(budget, ...)
INDEX(users, ...)
```

The `...` could be anything or nothing.  One index *may* be used, but only for the first column.

There is a chance that both such indexes could be used.  This is with the "index merge" facility.  If it were used, then the process would be to pull 100K ids from the `budget` index, 100K rows from the `user` index, then find the 3 ids that are in both, and finally look up the rows (`*`) for them.  The Optimizer decided that was not worth it, based on "50%" or "100K" or the phase of the moon.

Since 10% of the table meets the single criteria, the Optimizer *may* decide that it is faster to scan the table rather than bounce back and forth between the index and the data.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT`.